# How do I make dialogue text appear with a beeping effect?

Tags: text, sound-effects

I'm interested in old-school RPG dialogue boxes, where text appearing in dialogue boxes is accompanied by a subtle beeping sound. This is [demonstrated in a video here](https://youtu.be/BEvGYT7eyg0?t=128).

Is this morse code translated to audio?

How can I achieve such an effect?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text is displayed letter by letter, you can have a single 'beep' sound, and play it every time a letter is added to the text.

You can make some exceptions, for example, play a beep only if the letter is not a symbol, or to make it more dynamic, add an additional delay when a comma (or dot) is added to the text.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my game, wich is in Java.

```
public static String GetWords(String text, float wordCount)
{
    float words = wordCount;
    int soundcounter = 0;
    boolean IS_MARKUP = false;
    Random rand = new Random();
    // loop through each character in text
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    { 

        if(i == text.length() - 1 && SceneHandler.lineFinished == false){
            SceneHandler.lineFinished = true;
        }
        words--;
        if (words <= 0)
        {
            return text.substring(0, i);
        }

    }
    return text;
}
```

You just draw your text in your render/update method, I assume you have one, and you feed it the String you want to typewrite, the time elapsed (wich is just deltatime++) and at what character speed per second you want it to type.

```
GameTools.fontText.draw(fontbatch, GameTools.GetWords(fullText, timeElapsed * wordsPerSecond), 204, 143);
```

Comment: A non-discrete number of words!

Answer (score 0):

This is not morse code.

You don't need a library to do this.

You could achieve the same effect by having a sound file that has different lengths of beeps interleaved with silences. The sound file must be *loopable*. When the text starts to be written to the screen, you start the looping sound. And when the text is done being 'typed' to the screen, you stop the sound.

I would suggest you find a web site that offers free to use sound effects, load it in your favourite audio editor ([Audacity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/) could do the trick) and modify it until it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This little JavaScript code might help you

```
var textSpeed = 50;
var textHolder = document.getElementById('id');
var sound = new Audio(...);
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  textHolder.innerHTML += string[i];
  if(string[i]!=' '){   //if space sound doesnt play
    sound.pause();
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    sound.play();  
  }
  i++;
  if(i>=string.length){
    clearInterval(textTimer);   
  }
},textSpeed);
```