# How could I make the character sound beeps like in old school games?

Tags: sound-effects, voice

I've been searching around, but I haven't found any resource on how I could achieve this, like those old school character beeps.

I want to have my characters talk with beeps like in Undertale, or Phoenix Wright, or any other games like that, but I've no luck finding anything helpful.

How could I achieve a similar effect?

Edit : Here is an example video of what i mean : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5tX0GyG3_I When the text goes by, there's that deep beeping sound, that's what i meant

Edit 2 : What i mean is not how i get it to work, but rather how do i make a sound like that using a program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make dialogue text appear with a beeping effect?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113356/how-do-i-make-dialogue-text-appear-with-a-beeping-effect)

Comment: I would suggest you download [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) and start playing with the filters. Sound production is a skill in itself and takes time and practice.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for are 8-bit vocal synths, an example of which can be found on the following page:

http://www.freesound.org/people/TheOnlyPKMNmaster/sounds/182332/

Also a comment on the page suggests that http://www.blastbay.com/ produces software that will let you generate your own custom sound files producing this effect.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ideal situation for getting into procedural content.

What you need is relatively simple and doesn't matter if it sounds synthetic. A perfect fit for learning the ropes of procedural audio.

A good program to get into procedural audio with is PureData. It's free, cross-platform and open-source. It uses a graphical flowchart-like system for representing things that's designed with audio in mind.

Andy Farnell's book "Designing Sound" is all about designing procedural sound effects using PureData and includes a decent tutorial on the language (yes, PD is technically a programming language), but more importantly, helps you get a head for figuring out what you need to make a sound.

When it comes to actually getting what you've designed into your game, what you're making here is so simple you could just translate it by hand into C++ or whatever main language you're using. If you get into much more sophisticated procedural sounds later, you'll probably want to consider using a library like libpd to provide an actual PureData implementation in your game and just load in .pd files from disk.